# Calculator with Stacks in C

Tags: c

good morning, I am making a calculator with a "Stack" of 10 positions in the "C" lenguage. What I have to do is, for example, I write the number "50", I press ENTER and that "50" must go to the first position "01". Then I write another number, for example "20" + ENTER and 20 should go to position "01", "50" goes up to "02" and so on, always after pressing ENTER. I am using the Gotoxy for this.

I can manage to print the first number in position "01" but after that I don't know how to proceed.
I'm new to programming so excuse me if I don't realize obvious things, I'm trying to learn so if you can give me a hand I would appreciate it. Here I leave the code in case you want to try it and get an idea of ​​what I'm trying to do, thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void PilaPush();
void ImprimirPila();

int main() {
    printf(" ____________________________________________________\n");
    printf("|10:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|09:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|08:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|07:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|06:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|05:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|04:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|03:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|02:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|01:_________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|                                                    |\r\n");
    printf("|                                                    |\r\n");
    printf("|____________________________________________________|\r\n");
    printf("|_____1_____|_____2_____|_____3_____|__+__|__DROP[P]_|\r\n");
    printf("|_____4_____|_____5_____|_____6_____|__-__|__SWAP[S]_|\r\n");
    printf("|_____7_____|_____8_____|_____9_____|__*__|__DEL[D]__|\r\n");
    printf("|_____,_____|_____0_____|____EXE____|__/__|__NUM[N]__|\r\n");
    printf("|_____'_____|_ARRIBA[W]_|__ABAJO[Z]_|_____|_SWAP1[Q]_|\r\n");

    gotoxy(3, 12);
    PilaPush();
    ImprimirPila();
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    HANDLE Ventana;
    Ventana = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD Coordenadas;
    Coordenadas.X = x;
    Coordenadas.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(Ventana, Coordenadas);
}

typedef struct Nodo {
    int elemento;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} Nodo;

// funciones para utilizar un manejador global
Nodo *primero = NULL;

// Insertar un nuevo nodo a la pila
void PilaPush() {
    Nodo *nuevo;
    // crear el nuevo Nodo.
    nuevo = (Nodo *)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));  // Asignar de forma dinamica un espacio de memoria al Nodo
    printf(" ");
    scanf("%d", &nuevo->elemento);
    // Agregar el nodo al principio de la Pila
    nuevo->siguiente = primero;  // El nuevo dato ahora es primero, que apunta a (NULL)

    primero = nuevo;  // Primero (NULL) ahora es el nuevo dato
}

// sacar un elemento de una pila
void ImprimirPila() {
    Nodo *actual = (Nodo *)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    actual = primero;
    if (primero != NULL) {
        while (actual != NULL) {
            gotoxy(9, 10);
            printf("%d", actual->elemento);
            actual = actual->siguiente;
            gotoxy(3, 12);
            printf("                                                  ");
            gotoxy(3, 12);
        }
    } else {
        printf("No hay ningun dato ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)? Or how would you know what operation?

Comment: Hint: your entire menu can be done with a single `printf();`. Keep the first `printf(` and remove all others along with all closing `";` except the last. The  compiler will concatenate all the `"...." "..."` together.  1 call to `printf()` instead of 19 is the way to go.

Comment: The biggest problem you are fighting is you are mixing your *Interface* (how you interact with the user) with your *Implementation* (how you process the data). Keep them separate. You want to implement a stack where the first entry becomes the top of the stack. Keep a count of the elements in the stack and display the bottom 10 in your interface. (if you have less than 10, just display the entries you have starting with the top of the stack at the `count` position and the rest below.) You have a `nodo*` pointer  in your struct -- this is how you chain the entries together for display.

Comment: Instead of struggling with a linked list, your calculator will have room for 10-and-only-10 values... A persistent array (acting like a stack) would involve less work. Your display already shows the top to bottom of that array/stack... If the stack holds 3 values, display them from the bottom upward..

Comment: Note: my first comment should read "Keep the first `printf(` and remove all others along with all closing `);` except the last." (typo)